# aws airflow S3 operator using request payor option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

How can we use airflow aws S3 operator to copy/download a file from aws to localfile system using the `request payor` option.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RequesterPaysBuckets.html